# Substitute missing parameter in Apache rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

Can anyone tell me how to replace **first** double underscore('__') with a value like '_2000'.

`www.mysite.com/abc/Price_10000__10500__` -- this should be changed to `www.mysite.com/abc/Price_10000_2000_10500__`

Note that none of the data is static except 'Price_' in the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(Price_\d+)__(\d+.*)$ /$1/$2_2000_$3 [L,NC,R]
```